# Polynomials, Sum and Product

Tags: polynomials

If α and β are roots of the equation $x^2 +8x -5=0$, find he quadratic equation whose roots are $\dfrac αβ$ ,  $\dfrac βα$.

Can someone please explain to me how to do this question? 
Ive tried many times but no luck. THANKS

Comment: You say you've tried many times. Exactly what have you tried?

Comment: well, ive used someone of the rules that the textbook has provided me and worked from there but no luck

Comment: Which rules? If you include some description of your attempts in your post, someone can point out what went wrong.

Comment: rules like alpha +bets +gamma=-b/a etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^2+8x-5=0$$
roots are $\alpha,\beta$
so

$$\alpha+\beta=-8,\alpha\beta=-5$$

To find out eqn whose roots are $\dfrac {\alpha}{\beta}$ and $\dfrac {\beta}{\alpha}$ you need to find out its sum and multiplication

$$sum=\dfrac {\alpha}{\beta}+\dfrac {\beta}{\alpha}=\dfrac {\alpha^2+\beta^2}{\alpha\beta}=solve \;it?$$
you can find out above value:
and $$multiplication=\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}\times \dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}=1$$

quadratic eqn = $x^2$-(sum of roots)$x$+multiplication of roots=0
$$x^2-\left(\dfrac {\alpha}{\beta} +\dfrac {\beta}{\alpha}\right)x+\left(\dfrac {\alpha}{\beta}\times\dfrac {\beta}{\alpha}\right)=0$$

Comment: @iostream007 Can you please explain what after. I understand up to what you have posted.

Comment: @RedQueen10101 In last step just put the "sum" and multiplication of roots.well multiplication is 1.you've to solve for sum I left there in between

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that if  $r_1$ and $r_2$ are zeroes of the polynomial $x^2 + ax + b$, then $r_1 + r_2 = -a$ and $r_1r_2 = b$. Do you know why?

Answer (score 2):

Let $r$ and $s$ be any real numbers; then the equation $(x-r)(x-s)=0$ has $r$ and $s$ as roots. (This is a useful general fact.) Thus, one equation with roots $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ and $\frac{\beta}{\alpha}$ is

$$\left(x-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)\left(x-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)=0\;,$$

which when multiplied out becomes

$$x^2-\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}+\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)x+1=0\;.$$

Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of $x^2+8x-5=0$, you know that they are the numbers

$$\frac{-8\pm\sqrt{64+20}}2=-4\pm\frac12\sqrt{84}=-4\pm\sqrt{21}\;,$$

and from there you can calculate

$$\frac{\alpha}{\beta}+\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\;;$$

I’ll leave that part to you.

Comment: No need to solve the original equation.

Comment: @Stephen: I’m aware of that, but I think it useful and important for the OP to realize that the problem can be solved using only very familiar ideas: they should be fairly readily available even if slicker approaches are forgotten or not noticed.

Comment: But you are already using the relationship between roots and coefficients.  The fact that one can complete the problem without solving the original equation uses only that relationship again and elementary algebra.

Comment: @Stephen: So? Your preferred approach is conceptually still a bit less elementary.

Comment: I disagree.  It uses only what you used and more basic material.

Comment: @Stephen: The difference isn’t in **what** it uses, but in how it uses it.